# How to upgrade fedora 25 to fedora 26 alpha?

Tags: linux, fedora

I want to test something on fedora 26 alpha, but I don't want to reinstall the whole OS. Right now I'm using fedora 25, how to directly upgrade to fedora 26 alpha?

Comment: The fed26 alpha won't be released until early March. The development branch of fedora is called rawhide, and is what will become that alpha release. You can switch to the rawhide branch by following the directions at the link that follows. This will update you to fed26 but it is a pre alpha release. The usual warnings- don't do on main machine, backup any thing you want to keep, be prepared for an unstable system. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/Rawhide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My intention is to correct linuxdev2013's answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment on it.

I needed to do (note that there are no dashes before download):

```
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --releasever=26
```

I also needed to use `--nogpgcheck` to work around apparent `gpg` problems with the alpha kernel package, but I expect that is a temporary error.

By the way, the [actual documentation](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade) describes this process.

Answer (score 4):

Much easier and sane way for this.

Execute the following commands on the terminal one by one:

```
sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --releasever=26
sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

Once the install part is finished and it reboots run:

```
sudo dnf system-upgrade clean
```

...and enjoy your f26 alpha install (upgraded in-place)!

For more informations about the dnf system upgrade plugin see, https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade.